# Spring framework, custom function in PreAuthorize of controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new to spring and i'm trying to learn be developing a simple application.

This is the schema of the database:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3H4jd.png

It is very simple, each user must start by logging in, and once they do it, a list of the teams in which are administrators is displayed. That information is stored in the table *team_members*

```
INSERT INTO team_members (user_id, team_id, role) VALUES ('1', '1', 'admin');
INSERT INTO team_members (user_id, team_id, role) VALUES ('1', '2', 'admin');
INSERT INTO team_members (user_id, team_id, role) VALUES ('2', '2', 'player');
INSERT INTO team_members (user_id, team_id, role) VALUES ('2', '3', 'admin');
```

My problem arises when a user tries to edit or access the page to edit of one of the teams. This is my *controller* to do it:

```
@RequestMapping(value="teams/{id}/edit", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editTeamPage(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("edit-team-form");
        Team team = teamService.getTeam(id);
        modelAndView.addObject("team",team);
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

To be able to access this page, this user must be authenticated `isAuthenticated()`, however, I would also like to check if the *role* of the user in the table *team_members* is *admin*.
So my question is, what is the best way to do this? Should I insert an *if* in the beggining of every controller function that must verify this condition? Is there a cleaner solution for this?

I tried to create

```
package com.sports.beans;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("mySecurityService")
public class MySecurityService {

    public boolean hasPermission(String key) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and added `@PreAuthorize("@mySecurityService.hasPermission('special')")` to the controller function but it didn't work. Edit: the method mySecurityService.hasPermission(...) is not called

This is my `spring-security.xml`

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">


<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
<!-- enable use-expressions -->
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/user**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/teams/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

    <!-- access denied page -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
        <form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
            username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <csrf />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService">
            <password-encoder hash="bcrypt"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="mySecurityService" class="com.sports.beans.MySecurityService" />

</beans:beans>
```

`web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
         version="3.0">
  <display-name>Sports</display-name>

<!-- Spring MVC -->  


    <servlet>  
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>  
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
    </servlet>  
    <servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>  
    <listener>  
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>  
    </listener>  

    <context-param>  
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>  
        <param-value>  
            /WEB-INF/spring-database.xml,  
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml  
        </param-value>  

    </context-param>  

 <!-- Spring Security -->

 <filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
 </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>singleSession</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

  </web-app>
```

`spring-database.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                             http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
                             http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
                             http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                             http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
                             http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                             http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
                             http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                             http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">



    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_sports"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="lol123" /> 
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
           <list>
                <value>com.sports.models.User</value>
                <value>com.sports.models.UserRole</value>
                <value>com.sports.models.Team</value>
                <value>com.sports.models.TeamMember</value>
           </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="userDao" class="com.sports.dao.UserDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sports" />

    <bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="com.sports.service.MyUserDetailsService">
        <property name="userDao" ref="userDao"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/>
            <tx:method name="find*" read-only="true"/>
            <tx:method name="*"/>
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="userServicePointCut" expression="execution(* com.sports.service.*Service.*(..))"/>
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="userServicePointCut"/>
    </aop:config>
</beans>
```

`mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sports.*"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work? `@PreAuthorize("@mySecurityService.hasPermission('special')")` should work, however you are not passing your logged in user id (which you would need for the check), something like `@PreAuthorize("@mySecurityService.hasPermission(principal,'admin')")`. Of course your service method will need `hasPermission(UserDetails user, String key)`.

Comment: the method mySecurityService.hasPermission(...) is not called

Comment: it may be the order of your configuration files, see http://www.javatronic.fr/articles/2014/03/15/method_level_security_with_spring_security_and_spring_mvc.html

Answer (score 0):

In order for `@PreAuthorize` to impact the code, you need to ensure that you [enable method security](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-global-method). For example:

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
```

A common problem is users will define the security annotations on their controllers and the global-method-security element in the parent context. This will not work.

The global-method-security element must be defined in the same Spring Context as the resource you are trying to secure. So for example, if the root ApplicationContext defines the service bean you are trying to secure, it should also refer to the a configuration that contains global-method-security.

For your example, that likely means that all of the configuration should be picked up by the following in your web.xml:

```
<context-param>  
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>  
    <param-value>  
        /WEB-INF/spring-database.xml,  
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml  
    </param-value>  
</context-param>
```